# Using Unix command shell how to Move one file to another in subdirectory without using / and * in command?

Tags: shell, security, unix, command, code-injection

Move/Rename  sub1/file1.txt to sub1/file2.txt (sub1 is sub folder)
command should not have characters like / and *

Reason for doing this: OS Command injection through file name

Thanks

Comment: This is off-topic here I think, but `cd sub1;mv file1.txt file2.txt`?